# Is it possible to remove and move a row of listbox on itself?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Just like the UITableView on iphone.

[image]

users can remove or move a row on UITableView.
There is only one button to switch the UITableView to editing mode.

but for listbox on wp7 , I need 3 buttons, one for removing the selected row, one for moving the row up, one for moving the row down.

[image]

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone `ListBox` doesn't support these features out of the box, but it would be possible to add them yourself using a `DataTemplate`.

Here's a blog post about [creating a custom `DataTemplate`](https://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/) for your `ListItems`.

At a high level, you'll need to create a template that contains:

- Enter edit mode button
- Delete button
- Sort up/down buttons

Then in your code, you'll need to toggle the visibility of the delete and sort buttons, as well as handle user clicks on each of the buttons. Doable, but a fair amount of work.

In my opinion, a better option would be to use a approach that's different from what you might be used to but is more familiar to Windows Phone users: the `ContextMenu`. This control allows you to pop up a menu when the user performs a long touch (tap-and-hold) on an item.

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API) about incorporating this control into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [re-order ListBox here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2010/12/27/a-reorderlistbox-for-windows-phone-7.aspx). It shows how to retemplate the ListBox.

For removing on item, you just need to remove its data source item. See how to use [ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha).

If you want to show effect when an item is removed, use [Event Triggers](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/how-to-add-event-trigger-in-windows-phone-7) for the `Unloaded` event.